# Finding blocking calls in VS2010 solution

Tags: c#, asynchronous, blocking

I've been tasked with removing blocking calls from a C# app.  Turns out this is a requirement of the environment it'll be running on.  I understand the concept of a blocking call, however, I'm not sure where to begin finding existing blocking calls.

So a few questions:

1. For any given function, how can I tell whether or not it is blocking?  Is there any way besides looking up the documentation?
2. Is there any way to search for blocking in a project or solution?  Eg. some plug-in that could tell me?

Comment: I assume by "blocking" you mean a function that is called from the UI thread that takes more than a small amount of time?  For example, file IO requests can be considered blocking.  Or do you mean strictly blocking calls such as waiting on a semaphore or mutex?

Comment: @AresAvatar, Good question, the requirements doc doesn't differentiate at all.  Given the context, I'm assuming that file IO isn't included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic way I know of to find blocking calls.  Most blocking code is used for thread or process synchronization such as lock, Monitor.Enter, Mutex and Semaphore/SemaphoreSlim waits, CountdownEvent and Barrier class use.  There's also SpinLock and ReaderWriterLock/ReaderWriterLockSlim locks which block.

There are several Thread calls that are blocking.  Thread.Sleep can technically be considered a blocking call, though it lasts a finite amount of time.  Thread.Join waits for other threads to finish and is thus blocking.

For and While loops can be considered blocking as they will run until they are done, but usually they will use one of the calls above (especially lock) if they are waiting on a specific variable updated in another thread.

Keep in mind that removing any of these is likely to have a serious negative impact on thread safety.